# bash setenv command is not found

Tags: bash, environment-variables

When I am using the following command

```
         setenv CLASSPATH /path/mysql-connector-java-ver-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

error is

```
        bash setenv command is not found
```

When i find path of setenv by which command , then i found following path

```
 (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/home/ec2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/ec2/bin:/root/bin)
```

Answer (score 19):

`setenv` belongs to `(t)csh`, not to `bash` which is the default shell in CentOS. Use

```
export CLASSPATH="/path/mysql-connector-java-ver-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH"
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

Even better because more clean, use prefix notation (without `set`) on the command you want to invoke:

```
CLASSPATH=/path/mysql-connector-java-ver-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH ANOTHER_VAR=bla ATHIRD_VAR=blu java -...
```

Now the `java` process you invoke will be able to gather your temporary environment variable(s) `CLASSPATH, ANOTHER_VAR` and `ATHIRD_VAR`.

If you used `export`, then the variables will also be set globally(?), at least on the script's environment. And, values of variables which already existed would be overwritten by the new values.

Advantages of prefix notation:

- previous values of a variable should stay unchanged, i.e. in the case the old values are being needed later on, then there would be no need to save the old values of the variables which already existed in order to restore them after the invocation
- no need to `unset` your temporary variables for cleanup purposes after the invocation